# SVG with external images doesn't load them when embedded with <img> tag in browsers

Tags: svg, same-origin-policy

I made the following observation:

If I create an svg image that references an external raster image via `xlink:href` and try to load the svg in browsers, the external images are only shown if I use the `<object>` tag, but not when using the `<img>` tag.

Rendering with the `<object>` tag is quite slow and not as clean as using the img tag for images so I was wondering if there's a way to make it work through the `<img>` tag.

At first I thought it doesn't work because of a same origin policy, but even if the referenced image is in the same directory and I reference it through its name only, it wont load.

Any ideas?

Comment: Im curious about his too... so I hope some answers appear :)

Comment: good question, 'image' tag inside 'svg' works for me in ff/chrome, but not opera(

Answer (score 1):

Are you using IE? IE doesnt recognize SVG anyway. Microsoft is always ten years behind, yet they are more popular and far more costly, for some reason. Name brand propaganda?

SVG loads in Firefox. Both as an XML document referenced directly in the URL, and also if you embed it into an XHTML (fully XML compliant) document with proper namespacing, the SVG should render properly. The great thing about this option is that DHTML can manipulate your SVG.  Everything I said in this paragraph also applies to MathML, if youre curious.

Aside from that, SVG doesn't load from an image tag. I do believe Firefox is working on this upgrade, though. Im not entirely sure.

Using the object or embed tag is reasonable, I suppose... but one of my earlier fixes was to use an iframe.  Embed an iframe in your html that references the complete SVG file.  Using CSS you can make the iframe look flush with the rest of your document, appearing and acting like an image.  Encased in a div or span tag, you can have onhover and onclick event handlers.

Using the image tag, your src can be a PHP file on server side.  If properly coded and with the appropriate cgi apps, you can rasterize your SVG on server-side, and have that PNG data sent back to your image via the PHP src.

Comment: SVG works for me in an image tag in firefox and has for at least a year. [This page's first image](http://games.greggman.com/game/webgl-3d-perspective/) is an svg using an image tag. Or did I mis-understand your comment?

Answer (score 0):

There's no particular reason `<object>` should be any slower to load than `<img>` apart from possibly the interaction aspect (img's are static while object's are fully interactive documents). The images inside the svg should load in both scenarios, so it sounds like a bug in the browser.

Could you post a link to your example?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are at least 10 months behind...IE9 supports SVG, and pre-release versions (including a beta) have been out for quite a while. Check out www.ietestdrive.com to grab the platform preview - it's pretty good. In my opinion, parts of their SVG support are much better than Firefox currently (but they don't support SMIL yet).

Comment: If you want to create a website these days you need to support a wide range of browsers, so focusing on the latest and greatest doesn't help unless you wanna do a tech demo.